# Getting value fron json in ejs file

Tags: json, ejs

Below is my json file, I want to put `src` for my img element.

How can I access value from my json using keys `img1, img2, img3...` as I am **already** looping through.

*json file*:

```
{
  "img1": "http://yui.yahooapis.com/testassets/museum.jpg",
  "img2": "http://yui.yahooapis.com/testassets/uluru.jpg",
  "img3": "http://yui.yahooapis.com/testassets/katatjuta.jpg",
  "img4": "http://yui.yahooapis.com/testassets/morraine.jpg",
  "img5": "http://yui.yahooapis.com/testassets/japan.jpg"
}
```

*Ejs file*:

```
<% var img_content = JSON.parse(json['img-load.json']); %>
<body>
    <% for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) { %>
        <img id="img<%= i %>" src="<%= img_content[i] %>" />
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `img_content['img' + i]`, like this:

```
<% var img_content = JSON.parse(json['img-load.json']); %>
<body>
    <% for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) { %>
        <img id="img<%= i %>" src="<%= img_content['img' + i] %>" />
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

The `[]` work just the same as they would in normal JS code.

Comment: Thanks for that, you thought right. I have been struggled for quite a few time :)